# iif/oif and old fashioned Alias Addresses?

Tags: nftables

I have an `eth0` on which I have created VLAN 2554 (using `ip link add`).  And then I have added three addresses, giving each one a `label` (using `ip address add ... label eth0.2554:99`).  And `ip addr` shows me:

```
3: eth0.2554@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:5f:64:3f:d6:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.25.54.97/27 brd 10.25.54.127 scope global eth0.2554
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.25.54.1/26 brd 10.25.54.63 scope global eth0.2554:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.25.54.129/25 brd 10.25.54.255 scope global eth0.2554:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Should I be surprised that `add rule ... iif "eth0.2554:0" ...` is rejected "interface does not exist" ?

I'm guessing that netfilter knows nothing about the ":99" on the end of an "xxx:99" 'label'.  Either that or there is some other spell I need to cast to make this work ?

Answer (score 2):

Those labels are solely for human consumption; Linux doesn't do anything with them, and hasn't in over a decade. You can use the actual interface name `eth0.2554`, but you probably will want to use IP address in this scenario.

Comment: OK... so I get nil points for a stupid question :-(  Is it also a stupid question to ask where I discover what (if anything) the `label` in `ip address add` can be used for (other than as a filter in `if address show`) ?

Comment: Sorry: s/if address/ip address/.  Also other than as a filter in `ip address flush` (and `ip address save`, whatever that is.)

Comment: I suspect you've already found all the uses for the label.